# Capture only the numeric part with sed regex

Tags: bash, shell, sed, regular-expression

Why does the following does not work?

```
INTERNAL_NUM=$(grep -E '\s*internal_num\s*=' file.xml |sed -E 's/internal_num\s*=\s*([0-9]\+)/\1/') 
echo "$INTERNAL_NUM"
```

I would like to print out the actual number but it prints:

```
internal_num = 1234
```

The `grep` command prints `internal_num = 1234` so that part is fine. It is the pipe to `sed` that does not work.

Comment: What is in `file.xml`?

Comment: @Jesse_b: The grep gives `internal_num = 1234`. So that part is fine. The pipe to sed does not work

Comment: @Jesse_b: `echo "internal_num = 1234" | sed etc` does not work

Comment: @Jim: Could you show us your actual file? Is it a proper XML formatted file or a text file?

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU grep, you could write

```
grep -oP '\binternal_num\s*=\s*\K\d+' file.xml
```

But you should not be parsing XML with regular expressions. Perhaps you need something like this

```
$ echo '
      <root>
          <tag>
              <tag>
                  <wanted internal_num="1234" />
                  <wanted internal_num = "5678" />
              </tag>
          </tag>
      </root>
  ' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//@internal_num' -n
```

```
1234
5678
```

Please show your input file.

Comment: While this shows another way of doing the same thing, it does not answer the question, "why does this not work [as expected]?".

Comment: Regex are not a solution for parsing html/xml

Answer (score 1):

You are using extended regex, but still escaping `\+`, therefore it looks for a literal plus sign and does not invoke the substitution.

Try,

```
INTERNAL_NUM=$(grep -E '\s*internal_num\s*=' file.xml |sed -E 's/internal_num\s*=\s*([0-9]+)/\1/') 
echo "$INTERNAL_NUM"
```

Testcases (tested on GNU sed V4.2.1):

```
$ echo "internal_num = 1234" | sed -E 's/internal_num\s*=\s*([0-9]\+)/\1/'
internal_num = 1234

$ echo "internal_num = 1234" | sed -E 's/internal_num\s*=\s*([0-9]+)/\1/'
1234
```

**As other answers mention (and explain in good detail), you should seriously consider not using regex to parse XML though.**

Comment: The second snippet you pasted prints `internal_num=1234`

Comment: It works with my GNU sed V4.2.1.  So in that case you may also have to check other answers about portable `sed` options.  E.g. replacing `\s` with `[[:space:]]`

Comment: Or maybe using `sed -r` not `sed -E` (which is undocumented).

Answer (score 1):

Different tools and implementations/versions of a given tool support different regular expression syntax.

To be portable, you can limit yourself to the POSIX feature set:

```
s=[[:space:]]
sed -n "s/^\(.*$s\)\{0,1\}internal_num$s*=$s*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\2/p"
```

(assuming there's only one occurrence per line)

If you know you'll only run it on systems where `grep` supports `-o` and `-P` (for perl-like regexps) à la GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
grep -Po '(?<!\S)internal_num\s*=\s*\K\d+'
```